# Invalid Reference when checking recordset in subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to check to see if a subform has any records but receiving an Invalid Reference error at this line:

If Me.frmReceiptsSubform_Cust.Form.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then

It worked initially but now it always breaks on this line. Even tried rebooting my PC. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Try compact & repair,  2. On Standard menu bar - click on Debug > Compile Database.

Comment: Already compiled...

Comment: That's strange. Can you add the screenshot of the error.